# List of Mitzvot Kiyumis? (ie voluntary/ conditional mitzvot)

Tags: halacha-theory, mitzvah

Does a list of Mitzvot Kiyumis (voluntary/ conditional mitzvot) exist? Some examples I remember learning:

- **Vilna Gaon** ([Ma'aseh Rav 185](https://www.sefaria.org/Maaseh_Rav.185.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))- Eating Matzah the last 7 days of Pesach
- **Rav Moshe Feinstein zt”l** (Igros Moshe E.H. 102 <sup>1</sup>)- Mitzvah to live in Eretz Yisrael
- I've also heard Tzitzit mentioned as well.

Does such a list exist? If not should we make a wiki?

<sup>1 <sub>couldn't find the teshuva online but saw it cited several places, including this [OU Torah article](https://www.ou.org/torah/halacha/practical-halacha/the-mitzvah-of-making-aliyah-living-in-israel-today/)</sub></sup>

Comment: The teshuvah is in Vol. III which is notoriously missing from Hebrewbooks.org

Comment: For מצווה קיומית I think "conditional" is a better word - one is obligated if  a condition arises - e.g. Mezuza can only be applied if/when one has a house without one, Kiddushin only applies if one is to marry, Tzitzis applies when one has a 4 corner garment etc, and unlike "obligatory" Mitzvos that a person is obligated to fulfill, like Tefilin and Succah and Milah etc.

Comment: Are you sure we're talking about the same definition, because from your examples it is not clear what you mean?

Comment: Instead of editing in a list of ambiguous titles of the category you seek, why not edit in a clear description of what you seek?

Comment: @DoubleAA hmm- how so/ what do you propose?

Comment: I don't know what to write since I don't know what you want. You know what you want. Just write what you want.

Comment: https://www.yeshiva.org.il/wiki/index.php?title=%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA